# margin-bottom setting for label gives weird alignment in table

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css

If I do:

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="n1" id="i1"></td>
      <td><label for="i1">Label</label></td>
      <td>Foo</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

I get strange vertical alignment ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u39eV.png)).  The problem looks like

```
label {
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
}
```

from _reboot.scss.  If I turn that off, the vertical alignment is correct.  If I don't use a table:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="n1" id="i1"> <label for="i1">Label</label> Foo
```

the alignment is correct.  Unfortunately, I need to do it in a table.  Am I just doing it wrong?  I'm tempted to override the margin-bottom, but that seems kind of hacky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I've got this.  I still don't understand why 0.5rem is the default, but the right way to override that looks like `<label class="mb-0" ... >`.  That feels a lot less hacky than adding my own CSS.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/